# How to use Backup Of Live WordPress Site Locally on another Laptop

Tags: wordpress, localhost, backup

I am on Internship in IT Department of an Organization.
Right Now I am working on WordPress. I have created few Local Host Sites. Using XAMPP.
Now the manager gave me the backup files of their website and database file In a USB.
Please guide me how can I use that backup on my laptop locally. I am having trouble.
Please guide from copying those files from USB into my laptop to running the site locally.
Thanks.

Comment: You just need to files and database backup for setup site in local
And then change the URL in your .htaccess file and (wp_option) table BASEURL and HOMEURL

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder inside the XAMPP www folder and put all the files of
   WordPress in that folder.
2. Browse to phpmyadmin and make a database. Then import the database files that you received from the import tab of the database you've just created.
3. After you imported the database files, find a table that ends with `_options` click on it and inside that you will find two records with the `option_name` of `siteurl` and `home`. Replace their `option_value` with the local URL of the WordPress site you have just made in XAMPP.
4. Go to your WordPress folders, find the `wp-config.php` file, open it and edit the details for your database connection.

if anything was not clear, ask in the comments.